# It say TypeError: object bool can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import os    
import discord

client = discord.Client()
    
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as {0.user}".format(client))
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content == "Hi":
        await message.channel.send("Hi")    
    elif message.content == "Hello":
        await message.channel.send("Hello")    
    elif await message.content.endswith("birthday"):
        await message.channel.send("Happy birthday")
    
token = os.environ['TOKENS']    
client.run(token)
```

Comment: `elif await message.content.endswith("birthday"):` I don't think the `await` is supposed to be there...

Answer (score 3):

You accidentally `await`ed the condition in the third `elif` which is actually not an coroutine. This be able should fix it :

```py
import os    
import discord

client = discord.Client()
    
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as {0.user}".format(client))
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content == "Hi":
        await message.channel.send("Hi")    
    elif message.content == "Hello":
        await message.channel.send("Hello")    
    elif message.content.endswith("birthday"):
        await message.channel.send("Happy birthday")
    
token = os.environ['TOKENS']    
client.run(token)
```

[image: Result]